# Showing Mysql table data in html form with php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm showing data from Mysql table with php inside HTML table, but i need 2 more things to accomplish to the table:

1- How to Alternate colors for table rows to use 4 different css classes, I am using now class='success' i have 3 more that i want to use and each one should apply to each table row, how to do it? any simple example like a loop or something?

2- Data showing from the oldest record in the table to the latest one, and i want to show the reverse, so the last record shows first in the html table.

My code for this table:

```
<?php echo "<table class='table'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Order#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Submitted On</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr> </thead>"; 

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                      {
                      echo "<tr class='success'>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['lite_order_id'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['lite_item_name'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['lite_email'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['lite_country'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['lite_order_total'] . "</td>";
                      echo "</tr>"; }
             echo "</table>"; ?>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion from where you can ACTUALLY try something - use % modulo operator to calculate/apply diff classes at 1,2,3,4 ..for reverse..either reverse the array of DESC/ASC the query

Comment: can you please elaborate your first point more.

Comment: do you want alternate colors to each table row based on tag

Comment: Yes, i need to show each table tow with a different color, i have the css class ready, but don't know how to apply these 4 css class on the table, so the first table row will have green color, second red, etc up to 4 different ones i have in my css.

Comment: @AneedHamas have a look at my answer, it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Use `id` attribute to style individual elements. Check it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

2 - In your MySQL query, use `ORDER BY`:

(I presume you have an `id` column here)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `yourtable` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_orderby.asp)

Comment: Thank you, 2- worked, but 1- is not working, I know css but now the css class is being applied to one <tr> tag only and apply to all the results, how to use multiple css classes for the table row tag? this one i still have a problem with it.

Comment: @AneedHamas you need to use CSS `id`s, not classes. Scroll down the linked page ;)

Comment: How can i make a <a></a> link inside the echo "<td>" . $row['lite_order_id'] . "</td>"; so when the user clicks on the Order number it opens a page to show the order(s) details? Just did't work inserting the <a href='#'> error in echoing "" and the $row variable

Answer (score 0):

To get reverse records you can use mysql ORDER BY clause or PHP function array_reverse()